# when uploading image flask is throwing 400 error

Tags: flask

I have written this api code and when i upload image through postman it throws 400 error.
flask api code:

```py
@app.route('/user_image', methods=["POST"])
def user_image():
        uploaded_img = request.files['uploaded_file']
        img_filename = secure_filename(uploaded_img.filename)
        uploaded_img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], img_filename))
        uploaded_img_file_url = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], img_filename)
        description=description_value, short_description=short_description_value)
       
        return jsonify({'submitted_record': uploaded_img_file_url})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 400 error code means bad GET/POST request. Try this:

```py
@app.route('/user_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  //changed here <--
def user_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       *code.......*
```